# Proper use of "context" in a phrase

Tags: word-choice, phrases, differences, grammaticality

Which of the following phrases is correct?

> Everything is in some context.

or

> Everything has some context.

Answer (score 2):

I would say instead:

> Everything has context.

Both of your examples are not ungrammatical (though the first might be questionable), but *some* is unnecessary here and detracts from the meaning of the statement.

Also, *in context* often means *in its proper place*, so *Everything is in context* sounds a little like *everything is where it should be*.

Comment: IS this correct? 'Everything is contextual'.

Comment: Yes.  *[Contextual](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contextual)* means depending on context, so you are saying that everything depends on context, which makes grammatical sense.